# Voice Call Recording Others Voice Not Recorded

Tags: android, voice-recognition, recording

I am creating an app for recording voice calls which is working fine on almost all devices. My problem is that the incoming voice is not recorded while making a call with earphones. I tried a number of ways to achieve this but failed to overcome this problem.

I tried with `MediaRecorder` and `AudioRecord`.  As an example, here is my MediaRecorder sample:

```
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();                    
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);

mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);                    
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);                   
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);                    
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(phoneCall.getPathToRecording());

mediaRecorder.prepare();
mediaRecorder.start();
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Google has been explicitly not providing this functionality for a long time.

Comment: @Srikanth Could you please provide your MediaRecorder code so that we can have a better understanding of you issue which your'e facing.

Comment: Please provide [a minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: @yash786 please check my question is updated with sample code

Comment: @MaxvonHippel sample code updated

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use below code.

MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION); 
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200); 
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB); 
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(phoneCall.getPathToRecording());
mediaRecorder.prepare(); 
Thread.sleep(3000);
mediaRecorder.start();
```